# Should I split my data into training/testing/validation sets with k-fold-cross validation?

Tags: validation, machine-learning

When evaluating a recommender system, one could split his data into three pieces: training, validation and testing sets. In such case, the training set would be used to learn the recommendation model from data and the validation set would be used to choose the best model or parameters to use. Then, using the chosen model, the user could evaluate the performance of his algorithm using the testing set.

I have found a documentation page for the scikit-learn cross validation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) where it says that is not necessary to split the data into three pieces when using k-fold-cross validation, but only into two: training and testing.

> A solution to this problem is a procedure called cross-validation (CV for short). A test set should still be held out for final evaluation, but the validation set is no longer needed when doing CV. In the basic approach, called k-fold CV, the training set is split into k smaller sets (other approaches are described below, but generally follow the same principles).

I am wondering if this would be a good approach. And if so, someone could show me a reference to an article/book backing this theory up?

Comment: I am afraid you question doesn't fit well here. You shall be posting it at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross validation does not avoid validation set, it simply **uses many**. In other words instead of one split into three parts, you have one split into two, and what you now call "training" is actually what previously has been training and validation, CV is simply about repeated splits (in slightly more smart manner than just randomly) into train and test, and then averaging the results. Theory backing it up is widely available in pretty much any good ML book; the crucial bit is "should I use it" and the answer is suprisingly simple - **only** if you do not have enough data to do one split. CV is used when you do not have enough data for each of the splits to be representative for the distribution you are interested in, then doing repeated splits simply reduce the variance. Furthermore, for really small datasets one does nested CV - one for [train+val][test] split and internal for [train][val], so the variance of both - model selection and its final evaluation - are reduced.